# Named string format arguments in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using Python 2.x, and trying to understand the logic of string formatting using named arguments. I understand:

`"{} and {}".format(10, 20)` prints `'10 and 20'`.

In like manner `'{name} and {state}'.format(name='X', state='Y')` prints `X and Y`

But why this isn't working?

```
my_string = "Hi! My name is {name}. I live in {state}"
my_string.format(name='Xi', state='Xo')
print(my_string)
```

It prints `"Hi! My name is {name}. I live in {state}"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) doesn't alter the string you call it on; it returns a new string. If you do

```
my_string = "Hi! My name is {name}. I live in {state}"
new_string = my_string.format(name='Xi', state='Xo')
print(new_string)
```

then you should see the expected result.